# Nuxt Auth login - working on localhost, 301 and 405 on server

Tags: vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

My problem is, that login/logout works perfectly on my localhost, but as soon as I deploy it on a server I got 301 and 405 errors, with the "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST" message and I cant figure it out why is that.

My nuxt.config.js:

```js
  },
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        user: {
          property: 'data'
        },
        token: {
          maxAge: 86400,
          global: true
        },
        endpoints: {
            login: { url: '/api/auth/login/', method: 'post' },
            logout: { url: '/api/auth/logout/', method: 'post' },
            user: { url: '/api/auth/user/', method: 'get' }
        }
      },
    }
  },
  build: {
```

My login method:

```js
    async login() {
      this.errors = {};
      try {
          await this.$auth.loginWith('local', { data: this.loginForm });
          ...
      } catch (error) {
          if (error.response.status === 401) {
              this.inactive = error.response.data.message;
          }
          this.errors = error?.response?.data?.errors;
      }
    },
```

My Laravel api.php:

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
  Route::post('login/', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
  Route::post('register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
  Route::post('set-password', [AuthController::class, 'setPassword']);

  Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {
    Route::get('user/', [AuthController::class, 'user']);
    Route::post('logout/', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::post('password-reset', [AuthController::class, 'passwordReset']);
  });
});
```

And i will attach my network tab from my browser (first is on localhost/working, second one is on a server/not working):

[image]

[image]

I don't know what I'm messing up but after several days of debugging I'm hopeless. I've emptied every possible caches on the backend side so I'm thinking thats not the problem. But hopefully somebody else will be much more clever than me and can tell me what's going on.

Comment: Post the solution as an answer and **not** as a comment!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've solved it in the meantime. Laravel handles the / ending badly (tries to redirect), so removing it from auth endpoints fixes everything.